# Initialization of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsmutablearray

When we want to assign some value in NSMutableArray, First of all we have to initialize it.

We can initialize it in two way. One is

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

and the second is

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Then what is the difference between these two methods? and which is better option to use?

Comment: You could goto this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10474934/how-to-initialize-a-nsmutablearray-in-objective-c) will clear your understanding.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between \[NSMutableArray array\] vs \[\[NSMutableArray alloc\] init\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init)

Comment: With ARC there's essentially no difference, in the vast majority of cases.  I'd guess that the first is very slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using non-ARC project, in the first one, you have the ownership of array object & you have to release them.It returns an object that is only retained.The second one returns a retained and autoreleased object as  you don't have the ownership of array objects.

In ARC code, it doesn't matter which of these you use.

Refer [ARRAY CLASS](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSArray/array) and this [SO QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423211/difference-between-nsmutablearray-array-vs-nsmutablearray-alloc-init)

Answer (score 0):

**Alloc** : Class method of NSObject. Returns a new instance of the receiving class.

**Init** : Instance method of NSObject. Implemented by subclasses to initialize a new object (the receiver) immediately after memory for it has been allocated.

**New** : Class method of NSObject. Allocates a new instance of the receiving class, sends it an init message, and returns the initialized object.

**alloc goes with init**

```
new = alloc + init
```

The only benefit to using +new is that it is more concise. If you need to provide arguments to the class's initialiser, you will have to use the +alloc and -initWith... methods instead.

- new doesn't support custom initializers
- alloc-init is more explicit than new

General opinion seems to be that you should use whatever you're comfortable with.